# How to use the chain rule to find the derivative of the function?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

$$f(x)=\frac{3x^2+2\sqrt{x^3+\cfrac{4}{x^4}}}{(x^3-4)\sqrt{x^2+4}}$$

I've thought about this question for a long time but failed to get the answer. How to figure out the substitution $u$ of in order to use the chain rule? Thank you very much.

Comment: I can not see a straight forward sub to make this easy - My advice is to just take things slowly and book keep well.

Comment: I would mainly use the quotient and product rules. The chains rule will only be useful to derivate the square roots.

Answer (score 1):

we set $$f(x)=\frac{u}{v}$$ then we have $$f'(x)=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$ where
$$u=3x^2+2\sqrt{x^3+\frac{4}{x^4}}$$ then we have
$$u'=6x+2\frac{1}{2}\left(x^3+\frac{4}{x^4}\right)^{-1/2}\left(3x^2-\frac{16}{x^5}\right)$$
and $$v'=3x^2\sqrt{x^2+4}+(x^3-4)\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+4\right)^{-1/2}\cdot 2x$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: I don't know whether I am right or not but except for the numerator , logarithmic differentiation shall help. Although this easy , was just thinking whether that shall be easier

Comment: i have written all what you must know

Comment: Yes , I have solved it . I was asking saying whether logarithmic differentiation shall be easier haere

Comment: should i do it for you?

Comment: Thanks ! I have just worked it out both the ways ( log n this). Log one was bigger ! Thanks